# VSTO - How to get PowerPoint template folder?

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I'm coding a ribbon for use in PowerPoint.
How do I get the default template folder?

In Word I use `ThisAddin.Application.Options.DefaultFilePath[]` but that's not there in PowerPoint.

Have tried `Enviroment.SpecialFolder.Tempates`, but that didn't give me the default folder.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

This'll depend on the OS and the Office version.  For PPT 2007 and on running under Vista and later, it should be:

%appdata%\Microsoft\Templates

For any given version, manually do a save-as, choose to save as POT/POTX and PPT will automatically point you at its default template directory.

Comment: Yes, and that's why I'm looking for a solution like the one I use in Word: ThisAddin.Application.Options.DefaultFilePath[]